# iOS 13 Core NFC - How does one write an Empty message to erase a tag?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nfc, ios13, core-nfc

I'm trying to erase all the contents on an NFC Tag using Core NFC in iOS 13. If I look at the documentation for writing a tag I get the following function:

```
- (void)writeNDEF:(NFCNDEFMessage *)ndefMessage completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *))completionHandler;
```

I normally create a NFCNDEFMessage using the following function:

```
- (instancetype)initWithNDEFRecords:(NSArray<NFCNDEFPayload *> *)records;
```

InitwithNDEFRecords states that records is:

```
An array of payload objects for the message. To create an empty message, pass in an empty array.
```

Therefore my current function is:

```
//Create an array containing the records we will write.
NSMutableArray* writeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[tag writeNDEF:[[NFCNDEFMessage alloc] initWithNDEFRecords:writeArray] completionHandler:^(NSError* error) {}];
```

I believe that code to be passing in an empty array and it will not create an empty message on the tag to erase it. I get an error inside the completion block that when written to the log is the following:

```
Error Domain=NFCError Code=401 "Stack Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Stack Error, NSUnderlyingError=0x280fecc60 {Error Domain=nfcd Code=15 "Stack Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Stack Error}}}
```

If I do NOT pass in an empty array and actually have some records to write, it writes to the tag properly.

I see apps on the App Store do support erasing tags such as "NFC Tools". I reached out to the developer but he didn't answer my emails on how he did it.

How can I erase a tag on iOS 13?